# Ways to choose players in tennis match

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can a game of tennis doubles be played from $3$ men and $4$ women when each team contains $1$ man and $1$ woman?

Comment: @Dark Lord Are you sure it is $36$ because I am getting $72$.

Comment: @PrakharNagpal Yup, tho 72 is also an option. How did you arrive to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would simply be $\binom31$ ways to choose $1$ man (for the first team) and $\binom41$ ways to choose $1$ woman from $4$ women. Thus you get $\binom31 \cdot \binom41$ = $3 \cdot 4$ = $12$ ways to choose the first team.

The second team can be made in $\binom21$ $\Bigl($ ways to choose men $\Bigl)$ and $\binom31$ ways to choose ways, women.  Thus you get, 
$12 \cdot 6$ = $72$ ways of choosing teams.

Now divide the answer by $2$ because this includes both sides being different matches. Thus we get $36$ ways.

Comment: This answer assumes that the "first team" is somehow distinct from the "second team."

Comment: The question asked for number of ways to play a tennis match. So yeah 72 ways of choosing teams means 36 ways of playing the match

Comment: Once you're choosing people one at a time, it's a bit odd to use choice notation. C(n,1) is just n. There are C(3,2) ways of choosing the men,C(4,2) ways of choosing the women, and 2! ways of pairing them. That gives 36.

Comment: @Accumulation True.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** (*assuming that which side of the court each time starts on is irrelevant*)

Choose the two men and the two women simultaneously.

Then, choose which of the women is partnered with the younger of the two men.

Apply [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and arrive at an answer.